# how to create FTP server in namespace

Tags: ftp, namespace, network-namespaces, macvlan

Lets say i created two namespace in Ubuntu.

`ip netns add A`
`ip netns add B`

now create Macvlan corresponding to each namespaces

`ip link add macvlanA link wlo1 type macvlan mode bridge`

`ip link set macvlanA netns A`

`ip netns exec A ifconfig macvlanA 10.0.0.1`

and done the same with namespace B with ip `10.0.0.2`

I want to transfer files from one namespace to another using FTP server.
how can i do that?